# Make New Copy of Power Automate Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate

I have a rather complicated Flow that I want to use as a template to deploy to multiple lists/libraries. I did a "Save As" and made a copy, then changed the trigger to point to a different library (the library is a clone of the one I developed the Flow for). When I run the Flow Checker, it gives no errors, but saving or editing a new document in the target library does not trigger the flow to run. Is there any way to get the Flow to trigger short of building a new copy from scratch?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you turn the flow on after copying? By default, it would be turned off.

Comment: Yes, I made sure the flow was turned on before trying to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check if you have specified any trigger conditions. For example, flow should only fire on a specific content type.

Comment: I would double check the Library settings (site and library) in the trigger condition, preferably deleting it and adding back in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick which may help you, as you mentioned saving or editing does not trigger.

After you saving/editing, and the flow is not triggered, then edit the flow, simply do nothing and save it directly. Check if the flow has been triggered. In my end it works for a copied flow which does not trigger by item/file change.

It simply happens with some flows using automatic trigger. I am not an expert on flow so not sure what could be the reason, at least it will let you know if the flow is properly set.